# presentModalViewController doesn´t show naviagionbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, presentmodalviewcontroller

what do I have to do, to show a navigationbar in a view, that is presented via presentModalViewController?

I call the presentModalViewController from code.

When I segue to the same view in a storyboard, whitch in this case is embedded in a navcontroler, everything works fine.

Thx
Mica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a nav bar to a controller when presenting modally

```
    UIViewController* myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationContoller* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Then in myViewController's viewWillAppear method you can setup the a dismiss or close button for the modal controller.

Another way to do it if you are using a Storyboard is to just get the storyboard by name and instantiate the controller by identifier.

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard" bundle:nil];
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
```

In the second example myViewController is a UINavigationController in the storyboard file.
I'm assuming ARC for all the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question, you have a navigation view controller already present on one screen, and you want to open the next screen and still have it present.

In that case, instead of using [view presentModalViewController:animated:] on the view, use [NavController pushViewController:animated:] on the navigation view controller.

Comment: Thanks, I think in that way we have no modal behavior. For example if the navcontroller is embedded in a TabBarController.